# MySql connection from c# .NET console application doesnt return

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connect

I am attempting to connect to a remote MySQL database in a C# .NET console application. When my code executes the connection.open() method the debugger never returns to the next line. I am not sure if there is just horrible lag, or if the connection is being blocked on the remote server. I have the code wrapped in a try/catch, and I am not getting any exceptions back either. I do not have access to the remote MySQL database to make administrative changes. Any suggestions on where to begin debugging or possible answers...

Comment: try to telnet to the remote server to see if there's a connection.

telnet remotehost 3306

Comment: gets an error in Putty that says "Server unexpectedly closed network connection"..

Answer (score 0):

You can try some IDE like SQL WorkBench or any one compatible with your DB. And Check Weather you are able to make connection to remote Db from Your machine. Then move further .It should work.

Comment: I just installed HediSQL and I can connect fine to the db from the machine that my C# application is running on...